# problem in views, Class 'Student' has no 'objects' memberpylint(no-member)?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

when i create a variable students equal models.Student.objects.all()
it shows a problem Class 'Student' has no 'objects' memberpylint(no-member) ! 
but the syntax is true because i see this in django documentation !

```
def Students(request):
    students = models.Student.objects.all()
    con = {
        'students': students
    }
    return render(request, 'students.html', con)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUMxC.jpg)

Comment: Yes. Ignore pylint.

Comment: remove `models` from `models.Student.objects.all()`

Comment: i do it, but it show the same problem ! Undefined variable 'Student'pylint(undefined-variable)

Comment: import Student model from file where u have written that Student model to views